# Const Functions to an array from other file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 functions to const in my index.js:

```js
const funcE = require("../Functions/cmdError")
const funcH = require("../Functions/cmdHelp")
```

When I call functions must be like this:

```js
funcE.cmdError(args)
funcH.cmdHelp(args)
```

I want join 2 const lines into 1 line and how to call these funtions?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want join 2 const lines into 1 line"? Like this? `const funcE = require("../Functions/cmdError"), funcH = require("../Functions/cmdHelp")`

Comment: somthing like 
```const func = {['../Functions/cmdHelp', '../Functions/cmdError']}```

Idk how to write it exactly and how to use it to call the function if written like that

Comment: Just try it with the code that I have posted. Then you should be able to invoke the functions the same as you have described in your question.

Comment: Can you give me link to this post?

Comment: Please don't spam tags. Nothing to do with discord or discord.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it already, thanks everyone.

```js
const func = [require("../Functions/cmdHelp"), require("../Functions/cmdError")]
```

and call it:

```js
func[0].cmdHelp(args)
func[1].cmdError(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 possibilities to declare your constants in one line.

**Option 1**

The simplest way:

```js
const funcE = require("../Functions/cmdError"); const funcH = require("../Functions/cmdHelp");
```

**Option 2**

Use a comma and don't use `const` for the second declaration.

```js
const funcE = require("../Functions/cmdError"), funcH = require("../Functions/cmdHelp");
```

**Option 3**

Use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
> makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
> objects, into distinct variables.

```js
const [funcE, funcH] = [require("../Functions/cmdError"), require("../Functions/cmdHelp")];
```

This is how you can invoke your functions in all cases:

```js
funcE.cmdError(args)
funcH.cmdHelp(args)
```

This is what you can do, if you want to have 1 constant only:

```js
const func = [require("../Functions/cmdError"), require("../Functions/cmdHelp")];
```

Invoke the functions with:
`func[0].cmdError(args)` and `func[1].cmdHelp(args)`

OR

you could also declare an object.

```js
const functions = {
  funcE: () => require("../Functions/cmdError"),
  funcH: () => require("../Functions/cmdHelp")
}
```

Invoke the functions with:
`functions.funcE()` and `functions.funcH()`

Comment: How can I constant 2 functions into one name like `func` and call one of them? somthing like `const func = [require("../Functions/cmdError"), require("../Functions/cmdHelp")];`

Comment: `func[0].cmdError(args)` and `func[1].cmdHelp(args)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also reach your goal by doing this:

Create a new file, for example, *index.js.*
In this *index.js* file write your "requires" and export them.

```
const funcE = require("../Functions/cmdError");
const funcH = require("../Functions/cmdHelp");

module.exports = {
  funcE,
  funcH
}
```

Then you can require the *index.js* file where you want and access these functions.